# Safety in AC/DC converter

Tags: transformer, converter, ac-dc

To make an AC/DC converter with 230 V input, I have seen several circuits. Circuits that use a transformer to lower the voltage and that filter the signal to obtain a stable low voltage. I have also seen circuits with a diode bridge and a high voltage to low voltage DC/DC converter. I wonder which circuit would be more secure. From my point of view, the circuit with the transformer would be safer because there is an isolation with the 230 V while the other type of circuit, there is no physical isolation with the 230 V, which seems less safe to me.

In your opinion, which solution is more secure?

Comment: What do you mean there is no isolation? Usually there is. Both can be safe or unsafe. Also asking for opinions is usually off topic.

Comment: The HV-to-LV DC-DC converters can contain a transformer too. The inductance used doesn't need to be an inductor.

Answer (score 2):

If the DC-DC converter is transformer-isolated and has adequate insulation in the transformer and any other components that cross the barrier then it may be safe.

If either is poorly designed or poorly manufactured then they may be unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

> *From my point of view, the circuit with the transformer would be safer
> because there is an isolation with the 230 V while the other type of
> circuit, there is no physical isolation with the 230 V, which seems
> less safe to me.*

DC-to-DC converters (used inside virtually all of these types of power supply) use a high frequency transformer. It's usually a flyback transformer and, regulations are in place that govern the construction and testing of these flyback transformers (and regular old-fashioned transformers) to ensure user safety.

Both solutions are equally safe (or secure) if built and tested correctly. If in doubt, look for a supplier with a recognized name who have a recognized quality system.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! What is happening inside the "transformer less" ones convert the line voltage to DC then  convert that DC to a high frequency AC to power the small transformer. The higher the frequency the less iron and copper is need and the efficiency increases as there is less loss. It is isolated. This reduces the cost and size while keeping them safe.

Be sure it has the appropriate safety label for your country and it is not fake. This goes for all electronics, not only power supplies. Many pieces have the power supply built in. Using an external supply lowers the manufacturer cost of the widget and eliminates most of the safety requirements.